# Why do strace and ltrace cause EINTR to happen?

Tags: signals, system-calls, strace, ltrace, ptrace

Consider this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>

int main(void) {
       int epfd = epoll_create1(0);
       struct epoll_event event;
       event.events = EPOLLIN;
       event.data.fd = 0;
       epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 0, &event);
       epoll_wait(epfd, &event, 1, -1);
       perror("epoll_wait");
       return 0;
}
```

When I run this program by itself, resizing the terminal (thus generating SIGWINCH) doesn't do anything to it, and it keeps waiting for input on stdin. When I run it inside strace or ltrace, the SIGWINCH results in epoll_wait erroring with EINTR. My understanding of EINTR is that it's only generated if a signal calls a signal handler in your code, but I don't have any of them registered. I thought that strace or ltrace may have been setting one for me, so I tried explicitly setting it to SIG_IGN, but this still didn't stop the EINTR. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They use **`ptrace(2)`**, whose manual page comments

> While  being  traced, the tracee will stop each time a signal is delivered, ***even if the signal is being ignored***.  (An exception  is  **`SIGKILL`**,  which  has  its usual effect.)  The tracer will be notified at its next  call to **`waitpid(2)`** (or one of the related "wait"  system  calls);  that  call  will  return a status value containing information that indicates  the cause of the stop in the tracee.  While the tracee is stopped,  the  tracer  can  use  various  ptrace  requests  to  inspect and modify the  tracee.  The tracer then causes  the  tracee  to  continue,  optionally  ignoring  the  delivered  signal (or even delivering a different signal  instead).

and later:

> Note that a suppressed signal still causes system calls to return  prematurely.   In  this  case,  system calls will be restarted: the tracer  will observe the tracee to reexecute the interrupted  system  call  (or  **`restart_syscall(2)`**  system call for a few system calls which use a different mechanism for restarting) if  the  tracer  uses  **`PTRACE_SYSCALL`**.  Even  system  calls  (such  as **`poll(2)`**) which are not restartable after  signal are restarted after signal is suppressed; ***however,  kernel  bugs  exist  which  cause some system calls to fail with EINTR even though no  observable signal is injected to the tracee***.

By default, **`SIGWINCH`** is ignored, but it sounds as if `epoll` is similar enough to `poll` that the `EINTR` is visible to the caller (even with the restart).